# Retrieving vector using pass-by-reference doesn't propagate clearing the underlying vector?

Tags: c++, vector, pass-by-reference

I have a scenario where I obtain a vector of MyClass using pass-by-reference like so:

```
std::vector<shared_ptr<MyClass>>& x = myObj->getVector();
```

but when I do:

```
x.clear();
```

I was expecting the underlying vector in myObj to have a size zero because I retrieved it using pass-by-reference. However, this is not the case. Why is this?

EDIT:

The vector being returned is a data member, not vector created within `getVector()`.

EDIT2: This was `getVector()`:

```
std::vector<shared_ptr<MyClass>> myVec;

std::vector<shared_ptr<MyClass>> getVector(){
    return myVec;
}
```

Comment: Does `getVector` return by reference? If not, your code should not compile.

Comment: @ghostofstandardspast Nope it just returns the object BUT... I was lead to believe that the return type of the method is not what determines PbR/PbV, it is whether the calling code (the part I have posted above) has "&"? Also, I am returning a class data member...

Comment: If you return by value, your object is copied/moved/RVOd out. If you don't put the reference on `x`, it is copied/moved into `x`. As it is, your code is invalid as an rvalue cannot bind to an lvalue reference.

Comment: If It returns a value *copy*, not a non-const reference, then either you're using a compiler that allows non-const references to temp-vals (aka MSVC), or that code should puke. Either way, the original vector isn't getting cleared. *Show the declaration of* `getVector()`. If it doesn't return a reference, the member won't be modified.

Comment: Just changed getVector() and I see when I return & then the change propagates through!

Comment: it'd be useful to post the code of `getVector()` so we can double-check it is not creating a copy. The definition of the class of `myObj` would help too

Comment: @user997112: It is both.  A chain of references can be broken at any link.

Comment: @user997112 Ahem!! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: So you know, there are a couple steps that could be taken to make this more scalable. In C++11, the caller can use `auto &x`, while the function can have the return type `decltype(myVec) &`. In C++14, the function can simply have the return type `decltype(auto)` or `auto &`, effectively allowing you to "forward" the data member out. Say you wanted to use a `std::vector<different_shared_ptr>` later. Now you would no longer need to change anything but the declaration of `myVec` assuming what is done to the vector would still work.

Answer (score 4):

> It just returns the object

Then your compiler should not accept this code because the rvalue result of calling `getVector` cannot bind to `x`, an lvalue reference. Microsot's compiler is notorious for having a language extension to permit such an act, and this extension is hated by many.

> I was lead to believe that the return type of the method is not what determines PbR/PbV, it is whether the calling code (the part I have posted above) has "&"?

If being a reference is only determined by the caller, what would this do?

```
myObj->getVector().clear();
```

Instead, the function needs to return by reference in order for the caller to receive a reference to the object (making the above sample work fine).

If you decide to store the result of the function, the variable must be a reference, else the result will be copied or moved into the variable (copied in the case of the return value being a reference). The caller's variable is also permitted to be directly constructed into via RVO, but again, not when the return value is a reference.

C++ passes and returns *by value* unless a reference is used. The default is value-semantics, which you might think is bad, but ends up working out a lot better when move semantics start coming into play.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, I had a gut feeling, but the OP did elaborate in the comments. "Nope it just returns the object" Perhaps my answer could be better formatted to include the relevant foundations.

Comment: _'but the OP did elaborate in the comments.'_ That's bad behavior, and the OP should know (or found his rep within their daily cereals box :P).

Comment: @user997112 _'It was MSVC...'_ **Nope!**

Answer (score 1):

You can resolve this problem using couple of approaches.

1. Change the return type of `getVector()` to return a reference to the member data.

   ```
   std::vector<shared_ptr<MyClass>>& getVector(){
     return myVec;
   }
   ```

   Then, you can use

   ```
   myObj->getVector().clear();
   ```

   to clear the contents of `myObj->myVec`.
2. Add a member function `clearVector()` and call it.

   ```
   void clearVector(){
     myVec.clear();
   }
   ```

   Then, you can use

   ```
   myObj->clearVector();
   ```

Comment: I like #2. No sudo access to the object's vector.

Comment: @ghostofstandardspast I like the term 'sudo access' :)

Comment: I only just thought of it, so it's probably been done, but it just fits so perfectly, doesn't it?